# Trouble Accessing com port in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, port, modem

I'm trying to read and write to a usb modem that is using the com port 3 with this code.

```
 SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
 sp.PortName = "COM3";
 //sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
 sp.Open();
 sp.Write("AT<CR>");
 byte[] bytes = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
 sp.Read(bytes, 0, sp.BytesToRead);

 textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

But I get this error :

Access to the port 'COM3' is denied.

Someone have an idea ... 
Thanks

Comment: you might need to run the program with admin privileges

Comment: Just tried it, didn't change anything, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only open the port once. Maybe you're accidentally opening it more than once within your code or another program is using it?

Comment: Wow thanks, i've got the hyperterminal running :S 

But now I didn't get any error but it's not doing anything, by sending the AT command i'm suppose to get an 'OK' in return got an idea for that. 

+1 by the way

Comment: Ok, the next step is to make sure your settings are correct. These include the baud rate, parity, data bits, stop bits, and handshake. Were you able to get a reply from the device using hyperterminal? If so, check what settings you're using there. For a C# sample, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the example, I've user WriteLine instead of write, that fixed my problem